# Ruby - mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e) error is thrown when running gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apple-m1

I'm trying to run a Ruby project on my M1 Mac. However, I'm running into the following error when running `gem` in my command line:

```
<internal:/Users/matti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': dlopen(/Users/matti/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/strscan-3.0.3/lib/strscan.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/matti/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/strscan-3.0.3/lib/strscan.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e))) - /Users/matti/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/strscan-3.0.3/lib/strscan.bundle (LoadError)
```

After looking around to different StackOverflow posts regarding this error, I wasn't able to find a post dealing with `gem` not working. Any attempt to run `gem uninstall` or `gem -arch -arm64e` were not working, was getting the same error above.

Ruby version:
`ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin21]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the root cause of this error was because I initially tried installing the Gems on an Intel-based version of RubyMine on my M1 Mac. I think this tried to install the Intel dependencies, until it eventually hit an error due to architecture compatibility.

To resolve this issue, I removed the ruby-3.1.2 directory following `/Users/matti/.rvm/rubies/` and then ran `bundle install`. All my dependencies installed successfully.

Comment: Works with other ruby installers like _ruby-install_ (in `/Users/myuser/.rubies/3.1.2`), too. Additionally, I had to remove `/Users/myuser/.gem/3.1.2`.

Comment: Actually you can JUST remove the .gem directory and then run 'bundle install'.  You don't have to remove the ruby directory.